# mysql | Долго выполняется запрос

Tags: mysql

Подскажите плиз:
Запрос выполняется около 5 минут. В таблице pilot_3_intermediate 132040183 записей.

Индексы: domain_id, date, (domain_id, date)

```
select
 count(domain_id)
from pilot_3_intermediate
where date(date) = '2019-11-23'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индекс не может быть использован, потому что вы применяете функцию к колонке. кроме того эта самая функция вынуждена применяться к каждой записи по очереди, что так же замедляет.

```
  where date >= '2019-11-23' and date < '2019-11-23'+interval 1 day
```

должно работать гораздо быстрее. Если конечно я правильно понял перечисленные индексы и один из них просто по полю date и перед ним в индексе не стоит domain_id